# Deadlock phenomenon even when PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT attribute is set to mutexes

Tags: linux, pthreads, posix, real-time, preempt-rt

I am trying to make a realtime interprocess communication module.

In order to avoid unbounded priority inversion, deadlock, and chain blocking, I set PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT to each mutex.

below is how each mutex is initialized

```
pthread_mutexattr_init(&mutexattr);
if (pthread_mutexattr_setpshared(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PROCESS_SHARED)) {
     std::cout << "pthread_mutexattr_setpshared failed" << std::endl;
     exit(-2);
}
if (pthread_mutexattr_setprotocol(&mutexattr, PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT)) {
     std::cout << "Failed to set protocol" << std::endl;
     exit(-2);
}
if (pthread_mutexattr_setprioceiling(&mutexattr, priority)) {//max priority among tasks that can lock 
     std::cout << "set priority ceiling failed" << std::endl;
     exit(-2);
}
pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, &mutexattr);
```

There are exactly two mutexes(m1 & m2)
There are more than two threads(t1, t2, ..., tn)

Now I intentionally gave a deadlock situation in which some thread locks m1 first and then m2, while other thread locks m2 first and then m1

And with priority ceiling protocol is set to each mutex, the deadlock situation isn't supposed to happen
However, it still seems to happen.

Do you have any idea? Am I implementing it wrongly?

BTW each thread is set with SCHED_FIFO and some priority value 1 ~ 95

Comment: Where do you see that `PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT` is supposed to protect against deadlocks? I only see that it's supposed to protect against priority inversions.

Comment: PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT is priority ceiling protocol which is supposed to prevent deadlock.

Comment: PTHREAD_PRIO_PROTECT = Priority ceiling protocol (https://www.embedded.com/effective-use-of-pthreads-in-embedded-linux-designs-part-2-sharing-resources/)

Comment: I don't see anything in that link that says it protects against deadlocks.

Comment: Priority ceiling protocol prevents deadlock state (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/priority-ceiling-protocol/)

Comment: hmm.. Maybe I am understanding it wrongly.

Comment: Read that again. It's saying the opposite of what you think. "In Priority ceiling protocol an assumption is made that [...] It does not fall into a deadlock state." In other words, it doesn't keep you from deadlocking; it require that you keep yourself from deadlocking.

Comment: I am trying to implement a realtime IPC module with which multiple processes can share data through shared memory meeting realtime constraints. Any suggestion please?